# How to find something from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I am trying to make a contacts python project but I don't know how to fin da single user. I have tried to find from the file but I am not able to,  kindly give the code for that part. If you find any other mistakes kindly resolve that too
This is the code.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Feb 19 17:56:45 2020

@author: Teerth Jain
"""

import time

from transpositionDecrypt import decryptMessage as dm
from transpositionEncrypt import encryptMessage as em
key = 8
users = {}
users1 = {}
print("Welcome to Teerth's Contacts Saver and Reader...")
time.sleep(0.5)
r_or_w = input("Do you want or (r)ead or (a)dd or (d)el contacts: ")
if r_or_w == 'r':
    what = input("Do you want to read a single contact(y, n): ")
    if what == 'y':
        #here is the part where you need to give me advice#


    if what == 'n':
        print("Displaying the whole list...")
        q = open('contacts.txt', 'r')
        for liness in q:
            print(dm(key, liness.strip()))



if r_or_w == 'a':
    while True:
        addwho = input("Please enter the name: ")
        number = input("Please enter the number: ")
        file2 = open('contacts.txt', 'r')
        y = dm(key, file2.read())
        if addwho in y:
            print("User in contact list, please try again")
            addwho = input("Please enter the name: ")
            number = input("Please enter the number: ")

        users1.update(addwho = number)
        file1 = open('contacts.txt', 'a')
        q = f'{addwho} : {number}'
        file1.write(em(key, q))
        file1.write("\n")
        file1.close()
        print("Number is ciphered and added.")
        again = input("Do you want to add another contact(y, n): ")
        if again == 'n':
            break
```

There are no such errors now but if you can modify the code to make it better, kindly do it
Thanks

Comment: You apparently forgot to add your code to the question. Please use [edit] to do so.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, so here's a broad recommendation. Don't store complex data in a plain text file. Use a serialization module, such as json, pickle, or shelve. Or use a full-fledged database.

Comment: Kindly show me how to(Please edit and give the whole code)